# OpenCL kernel fails to compile asking for address space qualifier

Tags: opencl

The following opencl code fails to compile.

```
typedef struct {

    double d;
    double* da;
    long* la;
    uint ui;

} MyStruct;


__kernel void MyKernel (__global MyStruct*  s) {

}
```

The error message is as follows.

```
line 11: error: kernel pointer arguments must point to addrSpace global, local, or constant
  __kernel void MyKernel (__global MyStruct*  s) {
                                              ^
```

As you can see I have clearly qualified the argument with '__global' as the error suggests I should.  What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this error?

Obviously this happens during kernel compilation so I haven't posted my host code here as it doesn't even get further than this.

Thanks.

Comment: `__kernel void MyKernel (__global struct MyStruct*  s)` should it not have the `struct` keyword in between, seeing this is C?

Comment: @TonyTheLion I don't think so, it's been typedef'ed as MyStruct, so the struct is implicit. I think the problem is that he has pointers in his struct, which is not allowed. Why do you have pointers in your struct, what is their meaning? You cannot point to host memory from your kernel like that.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Adding the struct keyword does actually make the kernel compile successfully. But I'm not sure if that's doing what I want it to do. I'll explain in my next comment to Thomas.

Comment: @Thomas The above struct is intended to have a double, a double array, a long array and an unsigned int. In my host code I have an array of three of these structs (though could be more) that I'm trying to pass to the kernel as an argument and access each one using array indices. As a side note, adding the struct keyword does actually make the kernel compile but semantically is that doing what I want it to do?

Comment: @junkie Hmm, maybe Tony was right then, though if my C-fu is correct, struct should not be needed. Does the kernel actually *work* now? Or just compile? I've never tried having arrays inside structs, I do not see how it would work since a pointer is mapped to a cl_mem host-side, and your struct is already a cl_mem, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Well. The standalone exmaple of compiling the kernel works. But the real world code is much more involved and will take me more time to check if it works but I see what you mean by arrays not working inside structs. I'm not sure how to pass three lots of data in then. Do I flatten all the data into individual arguments to kernels? That's a lot of arguments. Though to be honest I can't do that because I don't know how many lots there'll be at compile time.

Comment: @Thomas Actually, removing the struct keyword and commenting out the arrays in the struct also makes the kernel compile so I think you're right. That's what's making it fail. Btw forgot to add your alias into my last comment which was addressed to you.

Comment: Ok. Figured out what I need to do to pass all the data in in a different way. Thanks @Thomas for helping me figure out what was wrong here. Btw Thomas you should add your answer as a real answer so I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have pointers in your struct, which is not allowed. You cannot point to host memory from your kernel like that, so pointers in kernel argument structs don't make much sense. Variable-sized arrays are backed up in OpenCL by a `cl_mem` host object, and that counts for one whole argument, so as far as I know, you can only pass variable-sized arrays directly as a kernel argument (and adjust the number of work units accordingly, of course).

You might prefer to put size information in your struct and pull out the arrays as standalone kernel arguments.

Comment: Exactly right. My testing proved that this indeed was the problem and in the end I also did extract the arrays to be standalone with offset information only in the structs. This kind of structuring of data is initially somewhat unintuitive and tedious but it does work and becomes more intuitive as one spends more time with opencl. Thanks.

Comment: @junkie You're welcome, and upon reflection, I believe the reason adding struct worked is because you were then not actually using the MyStruct type at all, but declaring a generic struct pointer, which OpenCL gladly accepts since it assumes you'll be casting it to some struct later on. Since you mentioned you were using a minimal kernel for testing, I guess the kernel was empty, so you were never casting anything and so it compiled, but not doing what you had in mind. Just a guess though.

Comment: That sounds plausible. My kernel was empty. Odd that it doesn't check the struct though still given that the name of the struct is specified. But I don't claim to understand this fully being new to all this.